# LG Display via USBC-HDMI indicating as active even after turning it off

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I have an LG 4K display connected via USBC-HDMI cable.
After turning it off physically with the button it remains active in MacBook Pro 16 settings and I can move the mouse there.
It happens also when connected via Apple adapter + HDMI-HDMI cable.

And it's working fine when connected via USBC-DP cable. When turning off the display, Mac switching to the internal display only mode.

Answer (score 2):

The USB-C ports on most MacBook Pro laptops all natively output a DisplayPort signal.  Most are Thunderbolt 3 though there are a few that are only USB with Alternate Mode display.    So, when you go from that USB-C port to HDMI, you're converting the signals.  That signal may stay high because the conversion isn't "clean."  This is why I always recommend using an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) that will recreate the signal versus a passive one that just "rearranges the signals."   I believe that will sort your issue as well.

However, on a DisplayPort input on a monitor, there's no conversion - the signal is clean.  So, when you turn it off, it's off.  **If you can use DisplayPort, then I recommend that over HDMI** There's no conversion and it's a better signal.

What you're seeing is just one of the many idiosyncrasies of HDMI.  If you're going from a HDMI source to an HDMI end device (monitor/TV), it works fairly well.  However, the moment you have to convert, that's where things start to go sideways.

- [What's wrong with HDMI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/398440/119271)
- [Macbook Pro detects the screen, but external screen stays black (mini dp to hdmi)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/157392/119271)
- [Logical HDMI display reconnection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283977/119271)
- [External Monitors Flicker when plugged into my Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384708/119271)

Comment: Thank you, Allan. Unfortunately, I can't use the HDMI cable, as it does not support DSC for 144hz. I need it for the Windows machine.